# tkinter checkbox select not work in function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write a tkinter a little app that updates the interface in a function rather then the main window but when i do this is can't selected the checkbox via '.select()' the exact code work in the main window.

i.e. the following works

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
checkvar1 = BooleanVar()
cb = Checkbutton(root, text="Show title", variable=checkvar1)
cb.select()
cb.place(x=25, y=25)
root.mainloop()
```

but the following doesn't is there way around this

```
from tkinter import *

def display_ckbox():
  checkvar1 = BooleanVar()
  cb = Checkbutton(root, text="Show title", variable=checkvar1)
  cb.select()
  cb.place(x=25, y=25)


root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
display_ckbox()
root.mainloop()
```

There no errors when running the script

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I can't really explain, *why* it is like that, but try the following:

```
from tkinter import *
def display_ckbox():
  cb = Checkbutton(root, text="Show title", variable=checkvar1)
  cb.select()
  cb.place(x=25, y=25)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x100')
checkvar1 = BooleanVar()  #this is the change
display_ckbox()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you create `checkvar1` in a function, it is a local variable which gets destroyed when the function returns.

Comment: Thankyou both, Thats was driving me mad. Very much appreciated